# good way to write an array of shorts into file with LittleEndian

Tags: java

I have a **short[512x512] array** need to write to a **binary file** with **little endian**. I know how to write **one short** to file with **little endian**. I think there is may be **better ways** than loop through the array writing **one by one**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhat like this:

```
short[] payload = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
ByteBuffer myByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
myByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

ShortBuffer myShortBuffer = myByteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
myShortBuffer.put(payload);

FileChannel out = new FileOutputStream("sample.bin").getChannel();
out.write(myByteBuffer);
out.close();
```

And somewhat like this to get it back:

```
ByteBuffer myByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(20);
myByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
FileChannel in = new FileInputStream("sample.bin").getChannel();
in.read(myByteBuffer);
myByteBuffer.flip();
in.close(); // do not forget to close the channel

ShortBuffer myShortBuffer = myByteBuffer.asShortBuffer();
myShortBuffer.get(payload);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(payload));
```

Comment: what if your short array is megabytes long, i think this will use up a lot of memory? is there a no way to do it without the copy?

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* need this to be fast, the best solution would be to put the shorts into a `ByteBuffer` with little endian byte order.  Then, write the ByteBuffer in one operation with a `FileChannel`.

Set the `ByteBuffer`'s byte order with the `.order()` method.

Comment: something like this: ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(shortArray);?